# How to find anti derivative of $e^{-5x}$?

Tags: calculus

I know how to take the derivative of this function(It would be $e^{-5x} *( -5)$ right?) but I'm stuck on trying to take the anti derivative of it. This is a small part of a larger integration problem I'm working on.

Comment: What's the derivative of $ae^{bx}$? What values of $a,b$ do you need so that the derivative is $e^{-5x}$?

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $ae^{ax}$, this can be easily seen by applying the chain rule and using the property of exponential function that derivative of $e^x$ is again $e^x$.

Since derivative is a linear operator, derivative of $be^{ax}$ is $b$ times the derivative of $e^{ax}$, i.e. it is $abe^{ax}$. By choosing $b=a^{-1}$, one gets that derivative of $a^{-1}e^{ax}$ is $e^{ax}$. Derivative of a function plus constant is equal to the derivative of the function because derivative of the constant is zero. This means that derivative of $a^{-1}e^{ax}+C$ is also $e^{ax}$, where $C$ is any constant.

Anti-derivative works another way, so anti-derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $a^{-1}e^{ax}+C$. Therefore, for special case of $a=-5$, one gets that anti-derivative of $e^{-5x}$ is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{-5x}}{-5}+C
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: considering that $e^x$ has an anti-derivative of $e^x$, try to find a function that has as derivative $e^{-5x}$. Can you go on from here?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the derivative.  Since the derivative is the original function multiplied by $-5$, the antiderivative is the original function divided by $-5$ plus a constant.  Try taking the derivative to confirm it.

Comment: I'm studying for a final and I have no idea how to do this problem. Could you explain it to me step by step?

Comment: I told you exactly what it is, and you can show yourself that it is correct by taking the derivative and getting the original function.